# Next-Auth & React.Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Next-Auth has the following example which is great for functions, however I have a class which I need to run `const { data: session } = useSession()` in it. I am wondering how can I convert it to make it valid in a class?

```
export default function AdminDashboard() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  // session is always non-null inside this page, all the way down the React tree.
  return "Some super secret dashboard"
}

AdminDashboard.auth = true
```

I tried to add session: useSession() to the following constructor but it did not work.

My Class

```
export default class AdminDashboard extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: null,
          areas:[],
          areasid:[],
          users: [],
          isLoading: true,
          isAreaLoading: true,
          session: useSession() // THIS DID NOT WORK
        };
        this.checkAnswer = this.checkAnswer.bind(this);
        
      }
}
AdminDashboard.auth = true
```

based on the answer below. I changed the script to be like this

```
const withSession = (Component) => (props) => {
  const session = useSession()

  // if the component has a render property, we are good
  if (Component.prototype.render) {
    return <Component session={session} {...props} />
  }

  // if the passed component is a function component, there is no need for this wrapper
  throw new Error(
    [
      "You passed a function component, `withSession` is not needed.",
      "You can `useSession` directly in your component.",
    ].join("\n")
  )
}



export default class NewCampaign extends React.Component {
render(){
        const { data: session, status } = this.props.session;
        const { isLoading, users, areas, areasid, isAreaLoading } = this.state;
        return (
            <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>
         )}
}

const ClassComponentWithSession = withSession(NewCampaign)

NewCampaign.auth = false;

NewCampaign.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return (
    <Dashboard>
      {page}
    </Dashboard>
  )
}
```

However, I am getting Cannot destructure property 'data' of 'this.props.session' as it is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [getSession](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession) and just **await** the result.

```
async function myFunction() {
  const session = await getSession()
  // session available here
}
```

You can use it both on client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `useSession()` hook in your class components you can do so with the help of a higher order component or with a render prop.

[Higher Order Component](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/usage-with-class-components#higher-order-component)

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"

const withSession = (Component) => (props) => {
  const session = useSession()

  // if the component has a render property, we are good
  if (Component.prototype.render) {
    return <Component session={session} {...props} />
  }

  // if the passed component is a function component, there is no need for this wrapper
  throw new Error(
    [
      "You passed a function component, `withSession` is not needed.",
      "You can `useSession` directly in your component.",
    ].join("\n")
  )
}

// Usage
class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data: session, status } = this.props.session
    return null
  }
}

const ClassComponentWithSession = withSession(ClassComponent)
```

[Render Prop](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/usage-with-class-components#render-prop)

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"

const UseSession = ({ children }) => {
  const session = useSession()
  return children(session)
}

// Usage
class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <UseSession>
        {(session) => <pre>{JSON.stringify(session, null, 2)}</pre>}
      </UseSession>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I call const ClassComponentWithSession = withSession(ClassComponent)

as I get an error Cannot destructure property 'data' of 'this.props.session' as it is undefined.

Comment: As per the docs `data` - This can be three values: Session / undefined / null.
when the session hasn't been fetched yet, data will undefined
in case it failed to retrieve the session, data will be null
in case of success, data will be Session.
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession